# Perl statement to change a value in file not working fine

Tags: regex, perl

I need to change statement 1 to statement 2 in a perl but its not working,.

```
statement 1 = label for ='answerone'
statement 2 = suspense
```

Using below statement but it do not works  :

```
perl -pi -e 's/<label for ='answerone'> /suspense/' /home/apanikar/public_html/tests/sub1/chp1/l1/q2.php
```

Comment: What are the `<>` and the extra space doing in the regex? And you'll have to escape the apostrophes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include `<`, `>` symbols.

```
perl -i -pe "s/\blabel for ='answerone'/suspense/g" file
```

I think it would be,

```
perl -i -pe "s/\\blabel for ='answerone'/suspense/g" file
```

OR

```
perl -i -pe 's/\blabel for ='"'answerone'/suspense/g" file
```

Comment: @Klas why you escape the `l`?

Comment: I was removing the b, didn't see the backslash. Bad edit (my fault).

Comment: Thank you Avinash and Klas - It worked successfully !!